# cancellation of NSOperationQueue does not work in swift

Tags: ios, iphone, multithreading, swift, nsoperationqueue

I'm trying to cancel all the threads in NSOperationQueue using swift but it does not work.

I'm trying start and stop the thread using NSOperationQueue when user clicks button. Also if time taken to execute myFunc is more than 20 seconds then timer will stop it and display alert.

Below is my code :

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var myTimer = NSTimer()
    var isSet = true
    var icount = 0

    let operationQueue = NSOperationQueue()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    var th123:NSThread!


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    func myFunc()
    {
        println("Thread start..")
    }


    @IBAction func btnClickEvent(sender: AnyObject) {

       if(isSet == false)
        {
            isSet = true
            myTimer.invalidate()

            // th123.cancel()
            operationQueue.cancelAllOperations()

            btnClick.setTitle("Start", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            //NSThread.exit()
        }
        else if (isSet == true)
        {
            isSet = false

            myTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(2, target: self, selector: Selector("checkTime"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
            NSLog("Timer started..")
            btnClick.setTitle("Stop", forState: UIControlState.Normal)

            Other()

        }

    }

    func myfunc1()
    {

    }

    func checkTime()
    {
        icount = icount + 10

        if( icount > 18 ) {

            isSet = false

            operationQueue.cancelAllOperations()

            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "iOScreator", message:
                "Opps Some Error occurred !!", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
            alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default,handler: nil))

            self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            myTimer.invalidate()
            btnClick.setTitle("Start", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        }

    }



 func Other() {

customOperation.completionBlock = {

    MyObject.myFunc()
}


var workerBlockOperation:NSBlockOperation = NSBlockOperation.self.init(
    block: {
        MyObject.myFunc()
    }
)


    operationQueue.addOperation(customOperation)
    operationQueue.addOperation(workerBlockOperation)


}


    @IBOutlet weak var lblstatus: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var btnClick: UIButton!
}
```

MyObject.swift file

import Foundation

```
class MyObject {

  class func myFunc()
    {
        NSLog(" myFunc called ")

        for i in 1...1000000 {
            println(i)
        }
    }

}
```

I would prefer to go with NSThread but i'm don't know how to forcefully stop/kill the NSthread.

I added below code but still not able to cancel task

Comment: All cancellation of an `NSOperation` does is set `cancelled` to `true`. Your operation should periodically check if it's cancelled, and stop any work when this happens. You're not doing this.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're actually trying to accomplish, but I've never seen `NSOperation` and `NSThread` mixed in this way. I don't know why your operation is using references outside of it (`self.th123`) but that is generally poor design. What is your actual goal?

Comment: @ Aaron Brager - my goal is when user clicks button start a thread which does some operation and when same button is clicked i.e. my thread should forcefully stop. Also while doing this my UI should not be blocked.Hence using NSOperation with NSThread.

Comment: Why do you need to use `NSThread`? Can you just do the work inside the `NSOperation`?

Comment: If you really want to do it this way, you'll need a separate thread reference for each operation. When you call `th123.cancel()`, that will only cancel the most recent thread, none of the other ones.

Comment: @Aaron Brager - i think i'm bit confused abt NSoperation and NSThread hence i messedup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cancelling `NSOperation` just sets it `isCanceled` property to true, it will not stop the execution of that operation, rest its up to you how you handle this, usually you will check for isCancelled before execution the code inside operation, something like this.

```
if (!op.isCancelled){
//its means operation (op) is not cancelled
// execute cod
}
```

**Update:**
If you are using NSBLock operation then it should be something like this

```
customOpeation =  NSBlockOperation ()
        customOpeation .addExecutionBlock {
            if !customOpeation.cancelled
            {
                // operation is not cancelled
                // so you can execute code
                myFunc()
            }
        }
```

If you want to get check if `operation` is `cancelled` inside `myFunc` method, then you will need to have operation reference otherwise it will execute, and if you have reference you can do something like this.

```
class MyObject {

  class func myFunc()
    {
        NSLog(" myFunc called ")

        for i in 1...1000000 {
            if operation.cancelled
            { //break loop as operation is cancelled
            }
            println(i)
        }
    }

}
```

How you will send reference of an operation to myFunc will depend how your app is architect.

**Recommended** 
Subclass `NSOperation` and add functionality inside that than you can easily check if operation is cancelled or not and this one is the recommended way

```
 class Opeation : NSOperation
    {
        override func main() {
            if !cancelled
            {
                myFunc()
            }
        }
        func myFunc()
        {
            for i in 1...1000000 {
                if cancelled
                {
                    break
                }
                println(i)
            }
        }
    }
```

After this just create an object of `Operation` and add it to `opeartionQueue`

Comment: with addOperationwithBlock if we create operation.. i'm not able to cancel it.

Comment: Yes you wan't be able to do that, that's what you are loosing by gaining short syntax, use NSBlock operation instead and pass a block inside init 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSBlockOperation_class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSBlockOperation/blockOperationWithBlock:

Comment: i added NSBlockOperation code but still not able to do so.